# Auto load alert using Sweetalert.js

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

Im using a plugin called **SweetAlert**. But on the examples provided, the alert can only be triggered when a button is click like this:

```
document.querySelector('.msg').onclick = function(){
    swal("Here's a message !");
};
```

But I want to apply this plugin on my login page so that when the username and password is accepted, the alert must be triggered directly, not on onlick event. Can anyone already used this plugin? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `swal("Here's a message !");` works outside a onclick handler too.

Meaning you can remove the first and last line of you example, like this:

```
swal("Here's a message !");
```

You're very new to this aren't you? Anyway, not judging.

I highly recommend http://eloquentjavascript.net/ and then http://speakingjs.com/es5/. You'll soon be a JavaScript ace!

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something went wrong with the query and produces a conflict. 
I suggest to try the code below and good luck.

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
    swal("Welcome!", "Welcome to the site!", "success");
  });
</script>
```